# Gson serialize BigInteger to number (not String)?

Tags: json, numbers, gson

I have an implementation of Gson that is serializing an instance of my custom class such that a BigInteger attribute has a String value like this:

```
"bigNumber":"12121211243123245845384534687435634558945453489543985435"
```

The requirement is a Number value, like:

```
"bigNumber":12121211243123245845384534687435634558945453489543985435
```

How is this possible in Gson?

Comment: What's the code you're using to do the serialization? Please [edit] your question with some code.

Comment: OP likely there is something fishy with your specific implementation. Please share the exact source code that is producing your results. Otherwise, consider accepting the answer here which points out that the default Java behavior is not what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I have tried the same thing with GSON and it is working fine for me.

Here is the code that I have tried :

JAVA class :

```
class Data{

    BigInteger bigNumber;

    public BigInteger getBigNumber() {
        return bigNumber;
    }

    public void setBigNumber(BigInteger bigNumber) {
        this.bigNumber = bigNumber;
    }

}
```

Code to serialize it to JSON :

```
Data data=new Data();   
data.setBigNumber(new BigInteger("12121211243123245845384534687435634558945453489543985435"));

Gson gson=new  Gson();
String jsonString=gson.toJson(data);
```

Output :

```
{"bigNumber":12121211243123245845384534687435634558945453489543985435}
```